# Callback/closure with JNR taking a pointer argument

Tags: java, c, jnr

I'm using JNR and trying to pass a callback function with the following C-equivalent signature:

```
int fn(void const*, void const**, void**)
```

into some C function. I have declared the callback nested in the JNR library interface on the Java side as:

```
public static interface Fn {
  @Delegate public int call(Pointer a, Pointer[] b, Pointer[] c);
}
```

with another function in the JNR library interface

```
public int doSomething(Fn fn);
```

to serve as a wrapper around `doSomething` in C code accepting `int(*)(void const*, void const**, void**)`. But whenever I create a callback:

```
new Fn() { int call() { ... } };
```

And pass it off to the `doSomething` method of my JNR library interface I get the runtime error:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

    Caused by:
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unsupported closure parameter type class [Ljnr.ffi.Pointer;
        at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.NativeClosureProxy.newProxyFactory(NativeClosureProxy.java:109)
        at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.NativeClosureFactory.newClosureFactory(NativeClosureFactory.java:84)
        at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.NativeClosureManager.initClosureFactory(NativeClosureManager.java:71)
        at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.NativeClosureManager.getClosureFactory(NativeClosureManager.java:49)
        at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.NativeClosureManager.newClosureSite(NativeClosureManager.java:81)
        at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.InvokerTypeMapper.getToNativeConverter(InvokerTypeMapper.java:68)
        at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.InvokerTypeMapper.getToNativeType(InvokerTypeMapper.java:143)
        at jnr.ffi.mapper.CachingTypeMapper.lookupAndCacheToNativeType(CachingTypeMapper.java:71)
        at jnr.ffi.mapper.CachingTypeMapper.getToNativeType(CachingTypeMapper.java:43)
        at jnr.ffi.mapper.CompositeTypeMapper.getToNativeType(CompositeTypeMapper.java:34)
        at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.InvokerUtil.getParameterTypes(InvokerUtil.java:185)
        at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.AsmLibraryLoader.generateInterfaceImpl(AsmLibraryLoader.java:125)
        at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.AsmLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(AsmLibraryLoader.java:59)
        at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:43)
        at jnr.ffi.LibraryLoader.load(LibraryLoader.java:265)
        at jnr.ffi.LibraryLoader.load(LibraryLoader.java:244)
```

What's wrong with my use of `Pointer`?

Comment: Found this: https://github.com/jnr/jnr-ffi/blob/master/src/main/java/jnr/ffi/provider/jffi/NativeClosureProxy.java#L227

For whatever reason, arrays of Pointer were supported at some point, and then commented out. Or they're an idea and are commented out until implemented? Or something?

Comment: Anyway, currently scrapping the `[]`s and just accessing Pointer elements through the Pointer arguments via `get` methods...

Answer (score 0):

If it is C calling Java, I don't think it is possible to give Java an actual Java array from barely a C pointer.

Firstly, a Java array object has a built-in length, but a C pointer value itself does not contain the upper-bound. C usually use conventions like zero-terminated strings, or passing two arguments (ptr, len).

Secondly, a Java array has to be populated before using (i.e. not lazy). This implies loading all pointers to the array, which may be inefficient. This also needs to be done with a known array length.

I suggest doing pointer arithmetic by yourself in Java when accessing a pointer to an array. This requires the knowledge of platform-specific memory layout (e.g. the length of one pointer element in the array of pointers), but all native interfaces are platform-specific.

Answer (score 0):

As [wks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/794965/wks) said,

> Firstly, a Java array object has a built-in length, but a C pointer value itself does not contain the upper-bound. C usually use conventions like zero-terminated strings, or passing two arguments (ptr, len).
>
> Secondly, a Java array has to be populated before using (i.e. not lazy). This implies loading all pointers to the array, which may be inefficient. This also needs to be done with a known array length.

As soon, as `void const**` and `void**` parameters are equivalent to array of **unknown size**, you should use `jnr.ffi.byref.PointerByReference` for these parameters as shown here:

```
public int call(Pointer a, PointerByReference b, PointerByReference c);
```

Then the usage of your  method should be like this:

```
Pointer a = new Pointer.wrap(Runtime.getSystemRuntime(), variable);
PointerByReference b = new PointerByReference();
PointerByReference c = new PointerByReference();
call(a, b, c);
Pointer bValue = b.getValue();
```

To manage data further you should know exactly what kind of data you are dealing with.